# Choosing group members with conditions

Tags: combinatorics

> There are two sets of individuals, A and B.
> Each has 9 members.
> Three smaller groups are to be built using these members.
> The first group is to consist of three individuals from A.
> The second is to consist of three individuals from B.
> The third group is to consist of three individuals from either A or B, but at least one from each.

**My attempt:**

Ways of choosing first and second group: $\binom{9}{3}=\frac{9!}{6!3!}=84$

Ways of choosing the third group (six individuals now remain in A and B) $\binom{12}{3}=\frac{12!}{9!3!}=220$.
Number of possibilities to subtract (cases where only A or B individuals are chosen for the third group): $\binom{6}{3}=\binom{6!}{3!3!}=20$. Multiply this by 2 for A and B. This gives the total

$$ \frac{9!}{6!3!} \cdot \frac{9!}{6!3!} \cdot \frac{12!}{9!3!}-2 \cdot \frac{6!}{3!3!}=84 \cdot 84 \cdot 220-40=1,552,280$$

This, however, is wrong. Where am I going astray?

Thanks

Comment: Haha! Thank you! I see, interesting, a bit surprising to me that the alternative way of doing it works..

Comment: @Bulbasaur  You should turn your comments into an answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of @N.F.Taussig's recommendation , i turned my comment into an answer in order to close the question.

What your mistake is that you forgot to use pharentheses to reckon your your calculation. The correct form must have been $$\binom{9}{3}\binom{9}{3}\times\bigg[\binom{12}{3}-2\binom{6}{3}\bigg]=84 \times84\times(220-40)=1,270,080$$

Moreover ,you can figure out this process by just saying that select one element from A and $2$ elements from B ,or select two elements from A and one element from B instead of making exlusion such as $[\binom{12}{3}-2\binom{6}{3}]$.

Then , $$\bigg[\binom{12}{3}-2\binom{6}{3}\bigg]=\bigg[\binom{6}{1}\binom{6}{2}+\binom{6}{2}\binom{6}{1}\bigg]=(6\times15)+(15\times6)=90+90=180$$